# "Unimplemented" gRPC exception is thrown when calling remote procedure when service marked with Authorize attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-status-code-404, grpc

Service code:

```
[Authorize]
public class ClientService : ClientServiceBase
{
    private readonly ISomeDependency someDependency;

    public ClientService(ISomeDependency someDependency)
    {
        this.someDependency = someDependency;
    }

    public override async Task<GetClientsResponse> GetClients(Empty request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
         //Remote procedure logic
    }
}
```

Services registrations:

```
builder.Services.AddGrpc();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISomeDependency, SomeDependency>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters =
       new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateActor = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = signingSecurityKey
        };
});
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapGrpcService<ClientService>();
});
```

gRPC client registration:

```
    services.AddGrpcClient<ClientServiceClient>(o =>
    {
        o.Address = new(Configuration.GetConnectionString("gRPC_Server"));
    });
```

**Problem:** When `ClientService` marked with `Authorize` attribute calling remote procedure causes RPC exception with message:"Status(StatusCode="Unimplemented", Detail="Bad gRPC response. HTTP status code: 404")". Otherwise everything works well.

**What I did:** I thought that this exception is thrown because I don't pass bearer token so I pass bearer token in headers but still this excpetion is thrown.

**Question:** Why exception is thrown when service marked with `Authorize` attribute and how to avoid throwing exception in this case?

Comment: See following : https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/grpc/grpc/+/refs/tags/v1.21.4-pre1/doc/statuscodes.md?force_isolation=true

Comment: Looks like adding parameter `AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer"` to `Authorize` attribute solves the problem. So this line `builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
` doesn't make sense. @jdweng any ideas why setting `AuthenticationSchemes` above controller solves the problem?